# Can SP Metadata be provided for the Spring Security SAML 2.0 extension (SP Initiated)?

Tags: spring, apache, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am trying to configure my Spring application to communicate with a third party IDP. My spring application is accessed through an Apache Webserver. However the Spring SAML extension automatically inserts the local address as the Assertion consumer address. This means that the IDP will not send the response through the Apache server.

Been struggling on it for 1 week. Came here only because I did not find an identical question posted.